# String toString method in BST (binary search tree)

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree, tostring

Why the next method does not print nothing but when i change the String s to array  , it works Properly?

not working:

```
public String toString(){
    //In-Order - left,root,right.
    String s ="";
    toString(root,s);
    return s;
}
public void toString(BSTNode root,String s){
    if (root!=null){
        toString(root.left,s);
         s=s+","+ root.data;
         toString(root.right,s);
    }
}
```

working:

```
public String toString(){
    //In-Order - left,root,right.
    String[] s =new String[1];
    s[0]="";
    toString(root,s);
    return s[0];
}
public void toString(BSTNode root,String[] s){
    if (root!=null){
        toString(root.left,s);
         s[0]=s[0]+","+ root.data;
         toString(root.right,s);
    }
```

Comment: What kind of error do you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an array of String and pass, basically it is creating String object (like we create using `new operator`). So it sues the same reference and modifies the String as you work on it. But in the former case, it treat them as two separate variable like the primitive type are handled in java.

```
public class StringTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String s[] = new String[1];
  System.out.println("before: "+s[0]);
  updateString(s);
  System.out.println("after: " + s[0]);
}
  private static void updateString(String s[]) {
  s[0] = "New String";
  }
}
```

output of the program is:

```
before: null
after: New String
```

Otherwise, it does not print anything.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is, that String is not a normal Reference-Type. If you change a String a new String is generated and the modified one is returned (String is immutable). (See String.replace() for example)
If you change your method to look like this, it should probably work:

```
public String toString(){
    //In-Order - left,root,right.
    return toString(root,s);
}
public String toString(BSTNode root,String s){
    if (root!=null){
         return toString(root.right,toString(root.left,s)+","+root.data);
    }
    return "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)  although this method does not work .

Answer (score 1):

Strings in java are immutable, this means that every time you assign them a new value a new object is actually created and the reference changes.